# Skip repeat for some columns in ng-repeat

Tags: json, html, angularjs

I wanted to have a table like this using angular repeat

HTML

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have written an Angularjs code for the above as follows.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td>{{row.month}}</td>
    <td>{{row.savings}}</td>
    <td rowspan="2">{{row.holidaysavings}}</td>      
  </tr> 
</table>
```

The td with rowspan gets repeated using ng-repeat which is not required.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: try ng-hide="{{$index > 1}}" or soemthijng similiar

Answer (score 2):

If you want the last `td` element only if `row.holidaysavings` is set (you didn't mention it, but it sounds like it!), you can use [`ngIf`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf).

`ngIf` is similar to `ngShow` with the exception that it removes it from the DOM instead of setting `display: none` if the expression is falsy (for example 0 or the empty string), which sounds like what you want:

```
<td rowspan="2" data-ng-if="row.holidaysavings">{{row.holidaysavings}}</td>
```

Comment: I have a change in json strucure.Now i am getting a nested array as follows: 
[
    {
        "holidaysavings": "$50",
        "months": [
            {
                "month": "January",
                "savings": "$100"
            },
            {
                "month": "February",
                "savings": "$80"
            }
        ]
    }
]
Help me with a way to show a table with as many rows as the no of months but also display holidaysavings in a table with rowspan equal to the no of rows for each array

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ng-class? Something like `<td ng-class='{rowSpanClass: row.holidaysavings >== "$50"}`